# Container is too close to the edges of screen on Firefox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.0.2 and I have custom CSS code like the following:

```
@media (min-width: 1680px) {
  .container,
  .container-fluid {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    max-width: 1750px;
  }
}
```

The thing is while I am on Chrome, it looks alright, there is a plenty of space between container and the edges. But when I open the page on Firefox, container edges are almost identical with the corners. (Same computer, same resolution etc.)

What could be the issue? I tried to add box-sizing: border-box !important; but didn't helped at all.

Sample snippet (please check container edges on both chrome and firefox):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .content {
    padding: 30px 0 60px 0;
    background-color: #F5FBFF;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1680px) {
    .container,
    .container-fluid {
      box-sizing: border-box !important;
      max-width: 1750px;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="boxes">
            <div class="img"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Sonet DSL Hizmeti" width="600" height="400" /></div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <h4>Leeroy Jenkins</h4>
              <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
                a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anything I could do to fix it?
Thanks!

Edit*

I am adding screenshots below:

Chrome
[image: Chrome Image]

Firefox
[image: Firefox Image]

Comment: For me it looks the same in chrome and firefox. Even when running the snippet in full screen.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Hello Mark, I uploaded screenshots of difference. Which one is correct on your end?

Comment: *I am using Bootstrap 5.0.2* - No you are not!

Comment: In the snippet it looks like the chrome one in both browsers. The full screen one has a lot of white(lightblue)space next to it in both cases, probably due to a high resolution on my system.  When I resize my window the white(lightblue)space  seems to jump around a bit. I guess this relates to your issue. I think bootstrap has some media queries that cause this, but I don't know much from bootstrap and don't have time to look into it. Maybe someone with more bootstrap experience can answer that.

Comment: I ran your code snippet on both Chrome and Firefox and both look exactly the same.

Comment: It turns out that I had custom `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` value in my Firefox configuration.. When I reverted it back to default, it started to look same..

Answer (score -5):

The issue you're facing with the container edges in Firefox might be related to the default browser styles applied to the .container class in Bootstrap. Each browser may have its own set of default styles that could affect how elements are rendered.

To fix the problem, you can try the following steps:

Reset browser styles: Include a CSS reset or normalize.css before your custom styles and Bootstrap CSS. This will help ensure a consistent starting point across different browsers.

Verify custom styles: Double-check if there are no other conflicting custom styles or CSS rules that might be affecting the layout.

Use the viewport meta tag: Make sure your HTML file includes the viewport meta tag in the head section. It helps in controlling the layout on different devices.

Ensure up-to-date Bootstrap: Check if you are using the latest version of Bootstrap. Sometimes, older versions might have compatibility issues with certain browsers.

Test with Browser Developer Tools: Use the Developer Tools in Firefox to inspect the container element and see if there are any styles being applied that you didn't intend.

Here's an example of how to include a CSS reset before your custom styles:

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
  <!-- Include a CSS reset or normalize.css before your custom styles and Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    /* Your custom CSS here */
    .content {
      padding: 30px 0 60px 0;
      background-color: #F5FBFF;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 1680px) {
      .container,
      .container-fluid {
        box-sizing: border-box !important;
        max-width: 1750px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your HTML content here -->
  <div class="content">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS (ensure it's included at the end of the body) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

By following these steps, you can increase the chances of having a consistent layout across different browsers, including Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This looks like so ChatGPT'ish answer :) Thanks though.